# Format specifier in printf() asks for an int when should be char

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers, format-string

I'm using Pelles C ide and I'm learning C, I thought I learned that %c was the format specifier for char in printf(), but it thinks I'm trying to use int? How can I correct this problem.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char z[] = "       *\n";
char m[] = "      *\n";
char k[] = "     *\n";
char o[] = "*   *\n";
char l[] = " * *\n";
char e[] = "  * ";



printf(" %c", z);
printf(" %c", m);
printf(" %c", k);
printf(" %c", o);
printf(" %c", l);
printf(" %c", e);



return 0;
```

}

Here is the errors:
[image]

Comment: They look like strings to me.....

Comment: @Martin Am I using the wrong specifier?

Comment: `z` (etc.) is not a `char`, it is an array of chars. Use z[0], for example, to print *one* char, or `%s` format to print the whole string (provided it's zero-terminated; in your case it is, as you initialize the arrays with a string).

Comment: `%c` is for single `char`, use `%s` for strings.

Comment: What would you like to accomplish? Print a special form out of '*'s ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a string specifier to output character strings.

```
printf("%s", z);
```

Answer (score 2):

`%c` means that *the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written*. For other types than `int` (including types promoted to `int`), the *behavior is undefined*.

For printing strings, use `%s`:

```
printf(" %s", z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable **z** by definition is a pointer to a char array.

try

```
printf(" %c", *z);
```

to print the first character pointed to by **z**.

If you want to print all of the characters, treat it as a string (pointer to array of characters with a terminating NUL character '\0'.   The NUL character is added automatically by the fact that your string is enclosed in double quotes.

try

```
printf(" %s", z);
```

Comment: `z` is not by definition a pointer to a char array. It is defined to be a char array. It is, at times, automatically converted to a pointer to a char (not to a char array). These are three different things: array of char, pointer to char, pointer to array of char.

Answer (score 1):

`printf(" %c", z);` `z` is a string no a char (string is an array of chars) to I think you're trying to do this `printf(" %c", '\n');` or this `printf(" %s", z);` (`%s` is the proper format specifier to output strings)

Answer (score 0):

A 'char' is passed as an 'int' when you call a function. But you're passing a *pointer* to 'char', and that is not the same thing at all. The error message is complaining that it's seeing a pointer. In your case, since you want to print a string rather than a single 'char', your format is wrong; use %s instead.

Comment: A `char` is promoted to `int` In this case, but not generally. A `char` is passed as an `int` when calling a function with no prototype or when it corresponds to a parameter position covered by ellipsis (“...”) in the prototype. Otherwise, a `char` is passed as the type specified by the corresponding parameter in the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want %c, define the variables as character constants:

```
char c = ' ';
char d = '\n';
```

and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array, then the name of the array variable (as in your code z,m,k,o,l,e) actually holds the base address of the array (that is the address of the 0th index of your array). So, when you try to print the value of z,m,k,o,l,e, they will return the base address of the respective array. You can check this by the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char z[] = "       *\n";
char m[] = "      *\n";
char k[] = "     *\n";
char o[] = "*   *\n";
char l[] = " * *\n";
char e[] = "  * ";



printf(" %d", z);
printf(" %d", m);
printf(" %d", k);
printf(" %d", o);
printf(" %d", l);
printf(" %d", e);



return 0;
}
```

The above code will not show any error and will print the base address of the respective array.

To make it more clear, you can try the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char z[] = "       *\n";
char m[] = "      *\n";
char k[] = "     *\n";
char o[] = "*   *\n";
char l[] = " * *\n";
char e[] = "  * ";



printf(" %c", &z);
printf(" %c", &m);
printf(" %c", &k);
printf(" %c", &o);
printf(" %c", &l);
printf(" %c", &e);



return 0;
}
```

The  above code again will not show any error and will print the 1st character of your respective arrays. I hope it makes you clear that why your code is showing error.

Now, when you use %s and the array name, then it will take the base address of your array and will print the whole string from that address till it finds null as follows. :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char z[] = "       *\n";
char m[] = "      *\n";
char k[] = "     *\n";
char o[] = "*   *\n";
char l[] = " * *\n";
char e[] = "  * ";



printf(" %s", z);
printf(" %s", m);
printf(" %s", k);
printf(" %s", o);
printf(" %s", l);
printf(" %s", e);



return 0;
}
```

And, if you want to print a particular character at a particular index of your char array, then you can try with the following code :

#include

```
int main(void)
{
char z[] = "       *\n";
char m[] = "      *\n";
char k[] = "     *\n";
char o[] = "*   *\n";
char l[] = " * *\n";
char e[] = "  * ";



printf(" %c", z[indexValue]);
printf(" %c", m[indexValue]);
printf(" %c", k[indexValue]);
printf(" %c", o[indexValue]);
printf(" %c", l[indexValue]);
printf(" %c", e[indexValue]);



return 0;
}
```